# Nodelet won't initialize in different manager

Tags: ros, nodelets

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have the following problem. I've created a nodelet and it runs fine, when I load it in a manager I created just for this nodelet. However when I try to load it into different manager that is in the system, the onInit() just won't get called.

What can be the possible causes of this problem? I have a suspicion that some other nodelet under the manager has blocking onInit() is it possible? Can I somehow list which nodelets run under the given manager?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52980/nodelet-won%27t-initialize-in-different-manager/) by [Scea](https://answers.ros.org/users/3567/scea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved. The output didn't go to the same console I started the nodelet from, but the nodelet was working.

---

Originally posted by [Scea](https://answers.ros.org/users/3567/scea/) with karma: 26 on 2013-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0